# How do I have multiple mutable references on a cortex-m0?

Tags: rust, atomic

I am writing code for a cortex-m0 processor which has no atomics. I want to be able to have one reference only for reading a value, and another for only writing a value. I want to implement design constraints that enforce only-writing and only-reading.

My objective is for the size of the variable stored to be writable with a single CPU instruction. This would normally be done with atomics that allow for read-modify-write, but I will not be doing read-modify-write, only read or only write.

The use case for this would be for an interrupt handler to write a value that is read by main code, or for main code to write a (different) value that is read by an interrupt handler.

I am imagining I would use the object like this:

```
let mut thing = get_new_thing(5 as u8);
let mut reader = thing.get_reader();
let mut writer = thing.get_writer();

reader.read();
writer.write(12 as u8);

///not allowed
reader.write(5 as u8);
writer.read();
```

Comment: As I understand it, you want to do read-only from the main thread on interrupt-routine-data. You can annotate the lifetime of main-thread and interrupt routine with a trait type + lifetime.

Comment: You likely want to use [`Typestate Programming`](https://rust-embedded.github.io/book/static-guarantees/typestate-programming.html).
The idea would be to define traits for (caller,allowed operation,callee) and to do the according writing/reading.

Comment: "single cpu instruction" This can be enforced using [AtomicUsize](https://rust-embedded.github.io/book/concurrency/index.html#atomic-access).

Comment: I think your example would fit great into the [Rust embedded book](https://rust-embedded.github.io/book/intro/index.html) as advanced pattern.

Comment: For an implementation I would need some concrete code.

Comment: To clarify:
 - Are your interruptions running on the same core as your normal execution, or are there several cores accessing the memory and there are possible synchronization issues, even though the M0 does not support synchronization between the cores?
 - Is what you want is for `write` to override the value everytime you write, and `read` to pull out the latest written value (if so, `read` and `write` may be better named as `get` and `set`), or do you need some form of queue?

Comment: @Jay-Pi The cortex-m0 does not provide atomic instructions. I was under the impression that this also meant that core::sync::atomic data types could not be used at all. Is this incorrect?

Comment: &Ten write always over-writes. no queue. My intention is for the interruptions to be running on the same core as normal execution (which is the case because there is only one core for this particular processor).

Comment: This [is a known issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/compiler-builtins/issues/114) for Cortex-M0. Use the according asembler instructions. [This](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0432/c/programmers-model/instruction-set-summary) should be the manual. If you use async, you need to additionally turn off the synchronization timer.

Comment: The solution omitted the interrupt routine [like here](https://rust-embedded.github.io/book/start/interrupts.html) where you annotate the according lifetimes. Interrupt routines cant save data, since after execution their lifetimes ends. You need `static mut THE_SERIAL_PORT: SerialPort = SerialPort;` as global mutable variable and change the below pattern accordingly. I will not reply further.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're doing bare-metal with Rust on an M0 single-threaded CPU, and wish to handle platform interrupts.

It seems your scenario is very particular, for two reasons:

- The CPU does not have any Atomics support because they do not make any sense considering there's only one core
- You still have some form of "threading" even though you're on a single CPU considering your code may be interrupted in the middle of anywhere for switching to handling an interruption hook. Interruption handlers should be considered as separate "threads", and you may not send them non-send data. In fact, in the bare-metal environment, [`Send` and `Sync` are dedicated for that purpose, and not for multi-core](https://github.com/rust-embedded/wg/pull/419).

The key point of the solution here is that even though there are no cross-core atomics on the CPU, *there should still be atomics in Rust core*, with at least support for `load` and `store`, providing safe mutable memory locations across interruptions, **a problem that is otherwise extremely hard to correctly solve**, due to the compiler being able to extensively optimize stuff supposing it's running on a single core and may not be interrupted. (For this reason, I'm not entirely convinced the other solutions proposed so far are correct, see [how this gets optimized](https://godbolt.org/z/1bGEKf).)

Using these atomics (and no unsafe), it looks like a solution to your problem would be the following:

Note: In order to follow the usual Rust semantics, you may want to use `.get()` and `.set()` as methods on your reader and writer (matches [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/cell/struct.Cell.html)). It also has the additional advantage that it removes the ambiguity on whether that's a single value you want to overwrite everytime, which I was not initially completely sure of when reading the question. I'm using these names in the implementation.

```rust
#![no_std]
#![no_main]
use panic_halt as _;

use cortex_m_rt::{entry, exception};

mod reader_writer {
    //! Simple wrapper to restrict a an atomic to read or write

    use core::sync::atomic::{AtomicUsize, Ordering};
    pub struct AtomicUsizeWrapper {
        inner: AtomicUsize,
    }
    impl AtomicUsizeWrapper {
        pub const fn new(val: usize) -> Self {
            Self {
                inner: AtomicUsize::new(val),
            }
        }
        pub fn get(&self) -> usize {
            self.inner.load(Ordering::SeqCst)
        }
        pub fn set(&self, val: usize) {
            self.inner.store(val, Ordering::SeqCst)
        }
        pub fn reader(&self) -> AtomicUsizeReader {
            AtomicUsizeReader { atomic: self }
        }
        pub fn writer(&self) -> AtomicUsizeWriter {
            AtomicUsizeWriter { atomic: self }
        }
    }

    pub struct AtomicUsizeReader<'a> {
        atomic: &'a AtomicUsizeWrapper,
    }
    impl AtomicUsizeReader<'_> {
        pub fn get(&self) -> usize {
            self.atomic.get()
        }
    }

    pub struct AtomicUsizeWriter<'a> {
        atomic: &'a AtomicUsizeWrapper,
    }
    impl AtomicUsizeWriter<'_> {
        pub fn set(&self, val: usize) {
            self.atomic.set(val)
        }
    }
}

use reader_writer::*;
static SOME_VALUE: AtomicUsizeWrapper = AtomicUsizeWrapper::new(0);

#[entry]
fn main() -> ! {
    let reader: AtomicUsizeReader<'static> = SOME_VALUE.reader();

    loop {
        reader.get();
    }
}

#[exception]
fn SysTick() {
    let writer: AtomicUsizeWriter<'static> = SOME_VALUE.writer();
    writer.set(12);
}
```

As you can see, this generates correct assembly:
https://godbolt.org/z/PsaKv9

To fully answer the question title, if your type happens to not be one of the standard types for which atomics are available (size greater than what you could write with a single operation), it looks like a solution would be to build a read/write restricting wrapper around `bare_metal::Mutex<core::cell::Cell<YourType>>` ([`bare_metal::Mutex`](https://docs.rs/bare-metal/1.0.0/bare_metal/struct.Mutex.html) is the same as [`cortex_m::interrupt::Mutex`](https://docs.rs/cortex-m/0.6.3/cortex_m/interrupt/struct.Mutex.html).)

[`bare_metal::Mutex`](https://docs.rs/bare-metal/1.0.0/bare_metal/struct.Mutex.html) could be used in the following way:

```rust
use core::cell::Cell;
use cortex_m::interrupt::{free, Mutex};

static SOME_VALUE: Mutex<Cell<u8>> = Mutex::new(Cell::new(0));

fn main() {
    free(|cs| SOME_VALUE.borrow(cs).set(5)); // This is how you store
    assert_eq!(5, free(|cs| SOME_VALUE.borrow(cs).get())); // This is how you read
}
```

(And you could use the additional same read/write wrapper as above for read/write restrictions, just reimplementing `get` and `set` using the `free` blocks)

Note: In the usual case, **when you're not handling interrupts** and you're executing on a single core, the simple following wrapper around [`Cell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/cell/struct.Cell.html) would do:

```rust
mod thing {
    use std::cell::Cell;
    pub struct Thing {
        inner: Cell<u8>,
    }

    impl Thing {
        pub fn new(val: u8) -> Self {
            Self { inner: Cell::new(val) }
        }
        pub fn reader(&self) -> ThingReader {
            ThingReader { thing: self }
        }
        pub fn writer(&self) -> ThingWriter {
            ThingWriter { thing: self }
        }
    }

    pub struct ThingReader<'a> {
        thing: &'a Thing,
    }

    impl ThingReader<'_> {
        pub fn get(&self) -> u8 {
            self.thing.inner.get()
        }
    }

    pub struct ThingWriter<'a> {
        thing: &'a Thing,
    }

    impl ThingWriter<'_> {
        pub fn set(&self, val: u8) {
            self.thing.inner.set(val)
        }
    }
}

use thing::Thing;

fn main() {
    let thing = Thing::new(5 as u8);
    let reader = thing.reader();
    let writer = thing.writer();

    reader.get();
    writer.set(12 as u8);
}
```

And if you needed to be able to pass these around with `'static`, using a `Rc<Cell<_>>` in all 3 structures would do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that I have come up with that implements a few features from [Alex Larionov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63254191/155423).

This should be limited to datatypes that can be written in a single CPU cycle (`u8`, `u16`, `u32`, `usize`, `i8`, `i16`, etc.). This code does not do that yet.

The `Nothing` type (fields `r`, `w`, `_b`) prevents multiple readers/writers from being gathered from a single `IntSharedData` and enforces the lifetime of the readers and writers.

The unsafe code works here because only one instance is writing the value, using one clock cycle at a time. Readers will always get a consistent view of the value they are reading.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct IntSharedData<T> {
    data: T,
    r: Nothing,
    w: Nothing,
}

pub struct UsableSharedReader<'a, T, OWNER> {
    d: *const T,
    _b: &'a Nothing,
    _owner: OWNER,
}

pub struct UsableSharedWriter<'a, T, OWNER> {
    d: *mut T,
    _b: &'a Nothing,
    _owner: OWNER,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Nothing;
pub struct Interrupt;
pub struct Thread;

pub fn new_data<T>(value: T) -> IntSharedData<T> {
    IntSharedData::<T> {
        data: value,
        r: Nothing,
        w: Nothing,
    }
}

impl<'a, T, OWNER> UsableSharedWriter<'a, T, OWNER>
where
    T: Copy,
{
    pub fn write(&mut self, val: T) {
        unsafe {
            *self.d = val;
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, T, OWNER> UsableSharedReader<'a, T, OWNER>
where
    T: Copy,
{
    pub fn read(&self) -> T {
        unsafe { *self.d }
    }
}

impl<T> IntSharedData<T>
where
    T: Copy,
{
    pub fn get_rw_to_interrupt(
        &mut self,
    ) -> (
        UsableSharedReader<T, Interrupt>,
        UsableSharedWriter<T, Thread>,
    ) {
        let r = UsableSharedReader::<T, Interrupt> {
            d: &mut self.data as *const T,
            _owner: Interrupt,
            _b: &mut self.r,
        };
        let wd = &mut self.data as *mut T;
        let w = UsableSharedWriter::<T, Thread> {
            d: wd,
            _owner: Thread,
            _b: &mut self.w,
        };
        return (r, w);
    }

    pub fn get_rw_from_interrupt(
        &mut self,
    ) -> (
        UsableSharedReader<T, Thread>,
        UsableSharedWriter<T, Interrupt>,
    ) {
        let r = UsableSharedReader::<T, Thread> {
            d: &mut self.data,
            _owner: Thread,
            _b: &mut self.r,
        };
        let w = UsableSharedWriter::<T, Interrupt> {
            d: &mut self.data,
            _owner: Interrupt,
            _b: &mut self.w,
        };
        return (r, w);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut element = new_data(5 as u8);
    let (r, mut w) = element.get_rw_from_interrupt();
    //let (mut a,mut b) = element.get_rw_from_interrupt();

    let v1 = r.read();

    w.write(5);
    let v2 = r.read();

    println!("v1: {}, v2: {}, t: {:?}", v1, v2, element);
}
```

Comment: I'm beleive we could use PhantomData instead of the Nothing(s). I'm not sure there was such a constraint as "only one reader and only one writer" in the original question, but if so that's an interesting implementation to guaratee this.

Answer (score -1):

Following Jay-Pi's suggestion, you could do something like this. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7bb42b225fcb36e9991c312976a08396)

```
#![allow(unused)]

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Thing(u8);
impl Thing {
    fn new(v: u8) -> Self {
        Self(v)
    }

    fn unwrap_rw(mut self) -> (ThingReader, ThingWriter) {
        (
            ThingReader(&self.0 as *const u8),
            ThingWriter(&mut self.0 as *mut u8),
        )
    }

    fn wrap_rw(r: ThingReader, w: ThingWriter) -> Self {
        Self(r.read())
    }
}

struct ThingReader(*const u8);
impl ThingReader {
    fn read(&self) -> u8 {
        unsafe { *self.0 }
    }
}

struct ThingWriter(*mut u8);
impl ThingWriter {
    fn write(&mut self, v: u8) {
        unsafe { *self.0 = v }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let t = Thing::new(5);
    let (reader, mut writer) = t.unwrap_rw();
    let v1 = reader.read();
    writer.write(10);
    let v2 = reader.read();
    writer.write(v1);
    let t = Thing::wrap_rw(reader, writer);
    println!("v1: {}, v2: {}, t: {:?}", v1, v2, t);
    // v1: 5, v2: 10, t: Thing(5)
}
```

I'm not sure how to do it in safe Rust, since you clearly want to have both reader and writer simultaneously (`RefCell` would require some runtime overhead). Notice that there's no synchronization, so multi-threading requires a `Mutex`.

Comment: If an answer is going to encourage random people who read this answer to use unsafe code, then it'd best explain why that specific usage of `unsafe` is correct and doesn't introduce undefined behavior.

Comment: I agree that it's a UB in most of the cases (need to enforce `ThingReader` and `ThingWriter`'s lifetimes to match `Thing`s)